# Not able to pass param to ng-inlude using ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am adding a template to my page using ng-include, but I want the header to have text that I want to pass from the parent controller. Data within the template is available through a separate listener. Heading is a value specified outside of it.

```
<div ng-include="'throughput.html'" ng-init="heading = 'CPU Throughput'">
```

This is my template controller

```
export class ThroughputController {
    heading: any;

    constructor(private $q: angular.IQService, private $scope: angular.IScope) {
        let vm = this;
        console.log(vm.heading);
    });
}
```

When my template's controller is initiated I'm not getting the value of heading in there. It is undefined.
I am able to write this same code in javascript and it all works. But my application is using TS and I'm new to TS and I don't know what I am missing. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.
We using AngularJS 1.6.

Comment: probably a typo in your post, but you're missing a double quote on the ng-init

Comment: Yes. Typo... Corrected it.

Comment: I haven't used TS yet either, but does setting it like `ng-init="vm.heading = 'CPU Throughput'"` make a difference?

Comment: Tried that as well. But that didn't work either.

Comment: This really isn't the intended use for `ng-init`.  I'm **going to make a guess here**, that your `ng-controller="ThroughputController"` is **inside** the `throughput.html` file;  this `ng-init` is not going to add the property to *that* controller, it will add it to whatever controller this `div` is contained within.

Comment: if you can post a [mcve] that shows the parent controller, the child controller,  and the HTML for both the page and the template, it will be easier to show how to pass the data you want from the parent to the child;  In most cases, though, if the child requires data from the parent, then you should consider making the child a component rather than using `ng-include`.

Comment: I am going with @Claies solution and that of many others who have answered similar questions. I'm creating directive to achieve my expected behaviour instead of using ng-include. Thanks!